# Merging ears with very-high-poly head sculpture

Tags: topology

I have made a head sculpture that at the moment lacks ears. Due to my inexperience in making them myself, I downloaded user-made ear 3d model. Now i want to merge it with my head but the problem is that topology of the head doesn't allow to make merging look seamless.  I tried using boolean and joining the objects. I also tried to simplify ear area on head with sculpting. What can i do to merge the two meshes seamlessly?

[image]

[image]

My first language is Russian -  I apologize for terrible grammar. (sorry for my English).
I am relatively new to blender.

Comment: Hello :). The visible seam happens when vertices aren't connected to each other. You can connect them manually through *Vertex > New Face*.

Comment: You might want to show your face mesh and  a face mesh taken the public domain made by an experienced person. Compare the two meshes as part of a tutorial for yourself.  Take a look at the ear area to see what is acceptable to an experienced person and what is not. Pay special attention to where 3 or 4 or 5 edges meet.  3 pole , 4 pole , 5 pole.  These concepts are discussed in tutorials.  If your face mesh has been reasonably done you can use it.  If your face mesh is [неприемлемо]  you can consider creating a new face mesh.  Sculpt mesh is not always the final mesh.  учебники хороши

Comment: Since your head is already triangulated and your ear is composed of quads, the easiest way would be using boolean union and using Blender 2.8x's new Remesh functionality and sculpt mode to create something that can be retopologized.